# Docker Proxy setting in format http:\\username:password@ip:port

Tags: docker, proxy

In Docker i am unable to set the proxy in the format http://:@IP:port

If I put this format in /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf it doesn't recognizes it.

But i put the proxy format as http://IP:port, then it recognizes it.

See below config

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/firstC$ cat /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf

[Service]
Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://1.1.1.1:8080"

ubuntu@ubuntu:~/firstC$ sudo systemctl show --property=Environment docker
Environment=HTTP_PROXY=http://1.1.1.1:8080
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/firstC$
```

But if i add user:password, then i do not get any result

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/firstC$ cat /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf

[Service]
Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://abd:def@1.1.1.1:8080"

ubuntu@ubuntu:~/firstC$ sudo systemctl show --property=Environment docker
Environment=
```

I am running a server behind corporate and need to connect to pull/push docker images. Even when i am building my own image it fails because of the FROM line

```
FROM ubuntu:bionic
```

So unable to do anything.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: all the special strings you have are needs to be URL encoded.

Comment: I have tried that only. In fact the same proxy URL is working fine for apt-get